# Why RedirectToAction changes ThreadID?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've an web application (ASP.NET MVC 3) with localization support for en-US, pt-BR, es-ES.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
  public ActionResult Index()
  {
    int threadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
    string threadUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.ToString();
    return View();
  }
}

public class LanguageController : Controller
{
  public ActionResult EN()
  {
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
  }

  public ActionResult ES()
  {
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("es-ES");
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("es-ES");

    int threadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
  }

  public ActionResult PT()
  {
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("pt-BR");
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("pt-BR");
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
  }
}
```

I start the app with culture en-US, with an ActionLink, I call the Language/ES to change to Spanish and redirect to index page. But don't work, the index page still in english...

I see the Thread Id is different on method LanguagesController.ES and HomeController.Index.

How is the best way to manage localization on ASP.NET MVC app?

Comment: Here is an article that might get you going in the right direction.  http://blog.stevelydford.com/2011/01/asp-net-mvc-3-internationalization/

Comment: Each request is handled by a different thread.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because each request is served from a thread which is drawn from the thread pool. So while the first request can be served on thread A, the second one could be served on thread B. You will need to persist the information about the current culture somewhere. This could be: session, cookies, some url route parameter, etc. Take a look at the following [localization guide](http://adamyan.blogspot.com/2010/02/aspnet-mvc-2-localization-complete.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think, in your controller, setting culture of session should work.

Session["Culture"] = new CultureInfo("es-ES");

or

HttpContext.Session["culture"] = new CultureInfo("es-ES");